# How to mock Series of calls on an Api wrapper with Mockito

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I'm new to Mocking and testing and I can't seem to figure out what I need to do test this api wrapper. I have a class that gets a list of tracks from a Spotify api call. I'm using this package https://github.com/thelinmichael/spotify-web-api-java/

I mock the SpotifyApi class so that during the unit tests it does not actually make calls to the api. But in order to get results back I need to make a series of calls, each that return a different class. I tried mocking each class and using them as the return for others but this causes problems. Not only do I need to know the breakdown of each class but in this flow some of the classes are final classes that I can't mock.
**SearchTracksRequest.Builder** in particular is a final class so the mocking fails.

It feel like I'm taking the wrong approach to this because it seems like a simple, common thing but I can't figure out how to get it testable. Am I going about this in the right way and how should I go about writing a test for this?

Here is the code that I am trying to test

The Class

```
public class Spotify {

    private SpotifyApi spotify;

    public Spotify(SpotifyApi spotify) {
        this.spotify = spotify;
    }

    public Track[] browse(String search) throws ParseException, SpotifyWebApiException, IOException {
        return spotify.searchTracks(search)
                .build()
                .execute()
                .getItems();
    }

}
```

The Test Class

```
class SpotifyTest {

    @Test
    public void test_spotify_can_browse() throws ParseException, SpotifyWebApiException, IOException {
        
        Track[] Exptracks = new Track[0];
        SpotifyApi mockSpotify = mock(SpotifyApi.class);
        
        SearchTracksRequest.Builder mockBuilder = mock(SearchTracksRequest.Builder.class);
        SearchTracksRequest mockRequest = mock(SearchTracksRequest.class);
        
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Paging<Track> mockExecute = (Paging<Track>) mock(Paging.class);
        
        when(mockSpotify.searchTracks("Spirit Of Radio")).thenReturn(mockBuilder);
        when(mockBuilder.build()).thenReturn(mockRequest);
        when(mockRequest.execute()).thenReturn(mockExecute);
        when(mockExecute.getItems()).thenReturn(Exptracks);

        Track[] tracks = new Spotify(mockSpotify).browse("Spirit Of Radio");
        
        assertEquals(tracks, Exptracks);

    }

}
```

Comment: You can configure Mockito to mock final classes, search for "mock-maker-inline". 

I would maybe consider using Spy for some of these classes. For example, let the builder class do whatever it needs (if that works) and only stub the ".build()" method to give you the mock SearchTracksRequest object.

In my opinion you can draw the testing line wherever you feel is sufficient. For example, only verifying the ".searchTracks(search)" method was called with your query might be enough. Testing the call chain of the library code is being made is tough to do when it is not your code.

Comment: I will checkout the mock-inline-maker but the more I look at things the only method that needs to work differently is `.execute()` because I don't want the API call. Is there no way to have it switch the SearchTracksRequest.execute() method with a custom return but leave everything else the same?

Comment: Yes, use spy instead of mock, spy leaves the object as and gives you the ability to stub some of its behavior. For what it's worth, look at the library's Github and see how they write their tests. It looks like they setup a mock SpotifyApi object and use it throughout their tests, you might want to do something similar.